# Can not make proper selection to make a face

Tags: modeling, faces

Here is what I'm trying to do.
[image: creating face from a tutorial]

This is what is happening.
[image: what is happening]

Learning from scratch and this is my biggest problem so far. Any help??

Comment: Did you by any chance press Alt while selecting the vertices?

Comment: Just select the 4 vertices one at a time, hold `shift` to add to the selection.

Comment: Alt+Select will do edge select. To select multiple vertices use Shift+Select

Answer (score 1):

i think you are hitting ALT as stated above, try this ... go to EDGE SELECT and select the two edges (easier then selecting 4 vertices anyways) then press F key